# Application icon in Delphi 2007 limited to 32 pixels

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

When i put an icon in my application using the menu Project > Options > Load icon, it will allow me a max size of 32x32 pixels.

This size looks nice in the app window, but the problem is, when there is a shortcut to the app on Windows desktop or Start menu, the icon is stretched to a larger size and looks blurred.

Is there a way to put a larger icon size in my app resource file, so Windows can use the larger size when needed ? If so, how to do it ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Delphi does not literally limit you to a 32 pixel icon, merely because the display of that .ico file only shows you the 32 bit file. I have used icons up to 64x64, I believe in Ancient Delphi versions (2007) and in modern Delphi versions, you can even use the full 256x256 icon size.    Remember that icons are intended to contain multiple sub-images and so you must simply author your .ico file with a tool that permits you to define a 48x48 or 64x64 image inside your icon file.  A .res file with {$r myothericon.res} can contain up to 256x256 vista size.

Comment: You can indeed go up to 256px icons, in any Delphi version. You'll need to use the MS resource compiler though to compile the resources.

Comment: Can't the IDE do that, these days? I must admit it has been ages since I designed an icon (actually, last one was for the Mac <g>) and had one compiled into a resource on Windows.

Comment: @rudy question is for d2007 and even now Borland resource compiler can't handle PNG images.

Comment: I know the question was for D2007, but I meant now, reacting to your comment. Thanks.

Comment: I could manage to use a bigger icon, but the problem is this bigger icon looks nice when i open it in any image editor, but looks blurred when Windows shows it in the app's desktop shortcut.  I'm still missing something here...

Comment: I use icons in D2007 that contain 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 64x64, 128x128, and 256x256 sized images, so that regardless of which icon is needed my app has one of the appropriate size. I used to provide multiple color depth icons too, but finally stopped bothering with that extra effort; all the machines now can handle the higher color depths. You need an icon editor that supports multiple resolution icons in a single .ico file. And no, we can't recommend one for you here; that question would be off-topic.